# installing dmsf plugin in redmine

Tags: plugins, redmine

while installing dmsf plugins, I ran the following command:

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"
```

Its throwing the following error:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- dav4rack
```

Is it due to my wrong setting of the gem file or something else? Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Its problem for nokogiri gem version not support You have to upgrade `nokogiri gem` or downgrade mention in the gem file